# html2pdf Call to a member function getParam() on null

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

Good day everybody!
Had downloaded html2pdf library.
Simple test works ok!

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML('This is my first test');
$html2pdf->output();
```

http://joxi.ru/ZrJR5jltQ3kL4r

but when I tried to convert real html

```
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
```

I got this
http://joxi.ru/EA4GObPUXP0Wy2
I really need to have this code worked.
Please help

Comment: For cross-referencing purposes, [this](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/703) appears to be you, too. To your problem, start with simple HTML, maybe just text wrapped in a `<strong>` tag. Then get more complicated. Looking [at the source](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/ec86c2b013e3a87aad34b1c09a67f7f9efcb24f4/src/Html2Pdf.php#L5986), this appears to be related to `<textarea>` tags specifically, does your HTML have that? There's also this [bug](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/454) that references the same thing.

Comment: Yes it was empty textareas - thank you